# Tokenization by date using nltk

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have the following dataset:

```
  Date                  D
_       
0   01/18/2020  shares recipes ... - news updates · breaking news emails · lives to remem...
1   01/18/2020  both sides of the pineapple slices with olive oil. ... some of my other support go-to's i...
2   01/18/2020  honey, tea tree oil ...learn more from webmd about honey ...
3   01/18/2020  years of downtown arts | times leaderas the local community dealt with concerns, pet...
4   01/18/2020  brooklyn, ny | opentableblood orange, arugula, hazelnuts, on toast. charcuterie. $16.00. smoked ...
5   01/19/2020  santa maria di leuca - we the italiansthe sounds of the taranta, the smell of tomatoes, olive oil...
6   01/19/2020  abuse in amish communities : nprit's been a minute with sam sanders · code switch · throughline ...
7   01/19/2020  fast, healthy recipe ideas – cbs new ...toss the pork cubes with chili powder, oregano, cumin, c...
9   01/19/2020  100; 51-100 | csnyi have used oregano oil, coconut oil, famciclovir, an..
```

I am applying `CountVectorizer` as follows:

```
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word', stop_words=stop_words)
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['D'])
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0] 
pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['Frequency']).sort_values(by='Frequency',ascending=False)
```

to get the highest frequency values for bi-grams. Since I would be interested in getting this info by date (i.e. grouping by 01/18/2020 and 01/19/2020 to get the bi-grams per each date), what I have done is not enough, since

```
  pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['Frequency']).sort_values(by='Frequency',ascending=False)
```

creates an empty dataframe with no information about `Date`. How could I grouped bi-grams per date? If I was interested in one-gram, I would have done something like :

```
 remove_words = list(stopwords.words('english'))


 df.D = df.D.str.replace('\d+', '')
 df.D = df.D.apply(lambda x: list(word for word in x.split() if word not in remove_words)) 

 df.groupby('Date').agg({'D': 'value_counts'})
```

I do not know how to do something similar using `nltk` and `CountVectorizer`. I hope you can help me.

Expected output:

```
Date         Bi-gram       Frequency
              
0  2019-01-01  This is         1
1  2019-01-01  some sentence   1
....
n-m 2020-01-01 Stackoverlow is 1
....
n   2020-01-01 type now        1
```

Comment: Another possible approach could be:     `from nltk import everygrams

list(everygrams(text.split(), 1, 2))`, but I do not know how to include it within my code

Comment: I guess you could first groupby date & then apply countvectorizer transform over it. CountVectorizer as the name suggests creates a list of words in sorted order (use `get_fetaure_names()`) & then assigns the number of times the word occured in the sentence at the corresponding index.

Comment: Thank you Aditya. I think I should group by date here: `sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['D'])` as it is the first occurrence for my dataframe when I use CountVectorizer. However, I think you are suggesting to do it before counting the frequencies..

Comment: Yeah, grouping by date after `fit_transform` should work

Comment: I think I have not understood how to do it :( I have tried as follows: `sparse_matrix = df.groupby('Date').word_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['D'])`, getting an error. `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'word_vectorizer'`. I do not know what should I group after fit_transform, if df or sparse_matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sample dataframe

```
         Date                 Sentence
0  2019-01-01    This is some sentence
1  2019-01-01  Another random sentence
2  2020-01-01    Stackoverlow is great
3  2020-01-01   What should I type now
```

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vec = CountVectorizer()
# fit on entire dataset to get count for a word across the dataset
vec.fit(df["Sentence"])

df.groupby("Date").apply(lambda x: vec.transform(x["Sentence"]).toarray())
```

This would give you the count of each word per sentence for a given date. As mentioned in the comment, you could map the index of a word in the given position using `get_feature_names()`

```
In [34]: print(vec.get_feature_names())                                                                                          
['another', 'great', 'is', 'now', 'random', 'sentence', 'should', 'some', 'stackoverlow', 'this', 'type', 'what']
```

Output -

```
Date
2019-01-01    [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
2020-01-01    [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
dtype: object
```

Consider, `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]` corresponding to the first sentence for the date `2019-01-01`. Here `1` at index 2 means the word is occured once in the first sentence.

Comment: Thank you @Aditya. However, I would need to have three columns, one for date, one for the bigrams and another for the frequency. I added an example of output in the question. I am sorry if I hadn't done earlier.